# Google Visualization: Detect if all hAxis labels are visible or not

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

First some introduction:

I'm using Google Visualization Charts to display some data in a graphical way. Everything is working fine and now I'm trying to improve it.

Now I want to detect if all the horizontal axis labels are visible or not. Google has this option define the behaviour of showing all the labels or just some of then by defining an interval.

When I set this option to auto, google figures it all out for you depending on the size of your chart. If the chart is not wide enough for showing all the x-axis labels then it will show the first, third, fifth, ...

I want to know whether or not the chart is showing all the x-axis labels so I can point the cliënt to a bigger chart which does have all the x-axis labels if not all the x-axis labels are shown.

I hope my problem is clear now and someone knows a solution to this. I don't want any suggestions about changing the style of the labels or some big workaround to get the same result, I just want to know if there is a solution to this.

Comment: Please explain what you want to do. If you want text for all values, why are you using the default? If all values aren't shown, what do you want to do?

Comment: When not all labels are displayed I want to show a message which points to a bigger view of the chart. Therefore I need to now if all labels are shown or not. I thought maybe there is a "flag" somehwere, which is true when all labels are shown or false when not. Maybe there is another way to find out.

Comment: Do you want to know if there is a label for each and every one of your values?